# How to add "Appendix" as an ToC entry (documentclass: 'article') before the appendices without a pagenumber

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, article, tocstyle

I have tried to add "Appendix" in my ToC between the main work and my appendices. I also don't want any page number to be displayed for this ToC entry.

So far I have managed to bodge in an entry like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberbox}{\csname @gobble\endcsname}%no page numbers for part  

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section in main text}
Bla bla bla...


\clearpage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}%TOC entry without page numbering 

\section{First appendix}
Bla bla bla...

\end{document}
```

This gives me an ToC entry that's is formatted like I want. But the hyperlink in the ToC points to the last page before the appendices.

How do I make the ToC entry so that the link points to the first page of my appendices?

Do you have any suggestions for a better/less tricky way of getting the TOC entry like i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to fake a contentsline with empty page numbers. `\addcontentsline` will cause the page number to be inserted, by using intermediate `.aux` file step.

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{part}{\appendixname}{}{}}
```

will first add the line

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {part}{Appendix}{}{}}
```

to the `.aux` file, the `\@writefile` command will then provide the correct line to the `.toc` finally.

Please note the `\protect`, since `\contentsline` is highly fragile.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberbox}{\csname @gobble\endcsname}%no page numbers for part  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section in main text}
Bla bla bla...


\clearpage
\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{part}{\appendixname}{}{}}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}%TOC entry without page numbering 

\section{First appendix}
Bla bla bla...

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**
The version with an explicit hyperlink to the appendix start (which is the same page as the first appendix section, in this case)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usetocstyle{standard}
\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberbox}{\csname @gobble\endcsname}%no page numbers for part  

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section in main text}
\blindtext[10]

\clearpage
\hypertarget{appendixstart}{\appendix}% Make a anchor here
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{part}{\protect\hyperlink{appendixstart}{\appendixname}}{}{}}

\section{First appendix}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```